# What are the serious problems caused by undefining object_id and __send__ on classes?

Tags: ruby

If I undefine all instance methods on a class then I get the following warnings:

```
warning: undefining `object_id' may cause serious problems
warning: undefining `__send__' may cause serious problems
```

What are some examples of "serious problems" this may cause?

(In particular, I am also curious as to whether this has any implications for garbage collection?)

Comment: I'm worried, instead, why are you trying to do so? And yeah, it does sound like a bad idea.

Comment: I guess undefining `object_id` will cause reference-equality checks to not work. You want them to work.

Comment: My suggestion: don't try to undefine any of the instance methods of `BasicObject`

Comment: I appreciate your concern (!), but I'm mostly curious.

Comment: Consider the case of inheritance. Ignoring the inevitable unknown method errors, if you remove the method from a base class, and all other classes rely on it, you've just blown Ruby's ability to process out of the water. That's why and how object-oriented code works; It relies on ancestor classes having methods that do certain things. So, while you can remove methods, you're also pulling the memory sticks out of HAL and will be left with an app that only drools and sings "Daisy" at best.

Answer (score 4):

In short, these methods are used for meta purposes (such as error reporting) as well as for ordinary purposes, so they are more important than other methods.

When something goes wrong, Ruby gives back an error message and backtraces. By default, an error message displays the inspection of the offending object. Except for a few special classes such `String` and `Numeric`, an inspection displays the object id. In order to display the error messages correctly, having `object_id` defined is essential. If it were not defined, then the error displaying routine itself would raise an error, which would need to be displayed, causing an infinite loop that cannot be reported. Under such situation, you have no way to tell what is going wrong. This is serious.

Perhaps the same can be said for `__send__`. It is the method that underlies `send` for most classes, and is crucial in sending instructions to objects.